# Determining the current ID of the element that called jquery/javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I am using the following jsfiddle code to determine uploaded image file's attributes. There are multiple file upload elements. I wish to know the current id of the element that has called the function so that I can use switch function. For example, if id = file1, then do this, elsif it is file2, then do this and so on. I used $(this).attr("id"), this.id; but none works.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    function displayPreview(files) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var img = new Image();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
            fileSize = Math.round(files.size / 1024);
            img.onload = function () {
                $('#preview').append('<img src="' + img.src + '">');
            }
        };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files);
    }
    $("#file1").change(function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        displayPreview(file);
    });
    $("#file2").change(function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        displayPreview(file);
    });
    $("#file3").change(function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        displayPreview(file);
    });
});
```

This is the html code:

```
<input type="file" id="file1" /></br>
<input type="file" id="file2" /></br>
<input type="file" id="file3" /></br>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

So, how do I know the id of the current element which has called the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the id of the element inside of your event handlers by using the event target

```
$("#file3").change(function(e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
    var file = this.files[0];
    displayPreview(file, id);
});
```

You will need to pass in "e" as the event in your anonymous function.

Alternatively, you can use a jQuery selector on this

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Once you have the id, pass it into your method.

```
displayPreview(file, id);
```

Comment: That did not work, however, that gave me an idea to make it workable. I did the following, and it worked for me. `$("#file3").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var file = this.files[0];
    displayPreview(file,id);
});`

Comment: @sridhar I'd be interested to know why it didn't work.  But yes, that's an alternative.  I'll update my answer to reflect it.